# WatchKit Custom Objects

Tags: ios, custom-controls, watchkit, apple-watch, ratingbar

I’m trying to create a rating bar in the WatchKit. However, I wasn’t able to create a custom button/image/label so far. While editing the storyboard, I am not able to change the images/labels/ buttons types; programatically I’m not able to add an object to the Interface Controller. Does anyone have an idea how to do this (or, if it is even possible)?

Answer (score 0):

It's a sad fact that watchOS is currently too restricted to run great apps with custom design. Since it doesn't support UIKit and is restricted in many other ways, you are **forced** to use a storyboard.

I'm sure that UIKit apps will come to the watch one day but today it isn't ready for it yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setHidden method. It will move up objects that below target controller.
But, if you want only hide, you can use setAlpha method.